# Router.js:135 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native. I'm trying to use Router from 'react-native-router-flux'. But I got this error:

```
Router.js:135 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')
    at Module../node_modules/react-native-router-flux/src/Router.js (Router.js:135)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
    at Module../node_modules/react-native-router-flux/src/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
```

My App.js:

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="Home"
          component={Home}
          title="Home"
          initial
        />
        <Scene
          key="Forgotpassword"
          component={Forgotpassword}
          title="Forgotpassword"
        />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
    </View>
    
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

My package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
   "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
   "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
   "expo": "~45.0.0",
   "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
   "react": "17.0.2",
   "react-dom": "17.0.2",
   "react-native": "0.68.2",
   "react-native-paper": "^4.12.1",
   "react-native-router-flux": "^4.3.1",
   "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.4",
   "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
   "react-native-web": "0.17.7"
 },
```

Edit : Earlier I forgot to add styles in my question. Now I added it my question. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Answer (score 0):

You gave your 'view'  a style of 'styles.container' but I cannot see anywhere in your code where you defined 'styles'. You can add custom styles to your View by using the below code:

```
const styles = Stylesheet.create({
// Write the styles here similar to CSS but in camelcase
})
```

Remember to import Stylesheet from react-native in your module. If you have already defined stylesheet in your code. Please include that in your question.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add styles in my question. now added

Comment: Don't forget to import Stylesheet in your file . Please let me know whether you have solved your problem